Exchanging data with Windows XP workstations in a corporate network
We have Windows XP workstations that are used to exchange data with other computers on the network. USB media isn't an option. Equipment on both ends of the link expect a Windows share (SMB).
For security reasons, we were planning to have the XP machines in a restricted VLAN configured so:

the XP machines don't see one another
that VLAN doesn't accept inbound/outbound traffic, except to a "relay" server.

The relay server would expose a Windows share (SMB), which would also be accessible from the "regular" computers. However, to do this, we need to enable SMBv1 on that server (since it's the only version supported by XP), which is an unacceptable security risk.
Plan B was to split the relay server in two. The first one (with SMBv1 active) would be located in the restricted VLAN, and would host the Windows share. It would be accessible by all XP machines, but also from the second server, located on the main network. The idea was to use DFS, so the second server would expose the data (even if it doesn't host it) to computers on the main network - but only over SMBv3. However, this doesn't work - under the hood, DFS remaps the requests to the server that physically hosts the data. And those requests are therefore denied by the firewall that controls the VLAN.
Plan C would be to have both servers host a complete copy of the data set, and use replication protocols, but I'm expecting that subtle synchronization issues (delays, corruption) will make it a nightmare. Looking for the tags to add to this post, I'm finding dfs-r. Is this what it's for?
What's plan D ? Using Linux and Samba for the two servers is an option, but last resort.

I dunno, sounds complicated. Maybe use FTP, SFTP, SCP, or something similar to transfer the files from the Windows XP computers to the server so that you don't have to enable SMBv1?

How about not using Windows XP at all.

XP is dead and that's also a reason why the question is off topic
